# Realme C25 stuck at recovery mode, after online update it turn into bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, realme

I am quite new to this kind of stuff.
I had this Realme C25 for relatively 2 years and a half.
For the past 2 weeks, somehow my volume down button doesn't respond at all but the physical button is still intact and doesn't seem to have any problems.

I let it slide until 2 days ago, my power button had the same issue as my volume down button.

I have enabled my double-click to activate. I have installed an app to turn up/turn down the volume and a power app to close my phone.

Because I remember it's been a long time since I restarted my phone, I restarted my phone with no alert in mind. But I was stuck at UI RECOVERY MODE, even after I powered it off and rebooted my phone, I was thrown into the UI RECOVERY MODE again.

Somehow the power button is working again.
I was tired at that time and decided to take a sleep while hoping my phone would run out of battery so I didn't accidentally wipe off my data.

Just now, in an MTCNA exam, I chose the install from online or something like that because some of my friends said "It seems a lot like the OS is kinda broken" and of course, I thought that's quite a way to put it.  I can use the mikrotik to optimize my phone connection so I did that. Afterward, I was hit by a full-blown BOOTLOOP in my head.

I could take it to the pro but since I am into networking and computer classes, I want to fix it by myself to take a knowledge or so (really bad move).

Since the volume down didn't seem to respond, and there is nothing to worry about losing my data on that phone (most of them are not that important and easy to get them), I want to know if there is a way to fix it.